# Listar itens de pasta compartilhada

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

Como listar itens de uma pasta especifica compartilhada com aplicação criada pelo **console de desenvolvedor?**

> O problema

Estou usando o pacote `googleapis` em node para obter um sistema de arquivos e upload de imagens mais flexível e robusto que as opções **"freemium"** de Heroku (em um app em Heroku) contudo não consigo listar apenas os itens de uma pasta compartilhada (compartilhada do usuário para a aplicação).

Ao tentar listar utilizando parâmetros como: `folderId`, `spaces` ou `corpus` o resultado é o mesmo... retorna todos os itens em todas as pastas do aplicativo ou compartilhadas (com exceção é claro da pasta "appDataFolder")

```
drive.files.list({
    auth: jwtClient, // token de autenticação
    folderId: '0B3ajCOYifSJ6a1ItaXFqaVB4alU', // folder id
    fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
    pageSize: 100
}, function (err, res) {
    if ( !!err ) {
        // Handle error
        console.error(err);
    } else {
        res.files.forEach(function (file) {
            console.log('Found file:', file.name, file.id);
        });
    }
});
```

Fonte ([postagem](https://medium.com/@abhimanyuPathania/google-drive-service-accounts-and-nodejs-a038b8ec482f)) que usei para compartilhar pasta entre usuário e aplicativo